# How should I react to a selection process with 48 hour coding project, plus an unpaid internship period?

Tags: interviewing

I connected with a very initial stage (bootstrapped) startup for a remote/international relocation job.

I found their selection process very peculiar. They gave me a 48 hour coding assignment. If I complete this, I will be accepted for a month long **unpaid** internship/probation period. After this we can discuss on working together. Not sure of the pay scale, or exact responsibilities, if I get selected.

All the conversation was over mail. No skype call to discuss things.

I found this very weird, and (as people have pointed out in the comments) somewhat offensive.

How should I react to this? Do other companies do this as well? I have given international remote/relocation interviews, and they have varied in the process but this one was just over the top.

**Update:**

The company is in Norway. I am looking for a full time job and not an internship. I have 3+ years of work experience. I am in the top 10% of professionals in my domain (software engineering) in my country (India).

Comment: An unpaid internship as a probation period doesn't seem all that different from an unpaid internship followed by being given an offer. Whether very rare or simply uncommon, it's mostly up to you to decide whether you want to work for a company that treats potential employees like this (although, if the first unpaid month is remote, I wouldn't be surprised if they also happen to decide to never keep anyone past that first free month).

Comment: It's up to you whether you accept this, or whether you run like hell. I know what I would be doing (smoke where the feet touch the ground).

Comment: Many companies will try anything they think they can get away with.

Comment: Down-voters care to comment?

Comment: RE: request for feedback: If you are in the top 10% of professionals do you really think you should have to do an unpaid internship.  Either you have grossly overestimated your abilities or you are just trolling.

Comment: Not trolling. I was looking for a full-time job, and I got this

Comment: @vedant1811 - Did you ask them why the insulting offer?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere and IDrinkandIKnowThings: updated my question.

Comment: Think about it: if your first experience with them is cause for so much hesitation and caution, how likely is it that these experiences will continue over the course of your employment with them? I would say quite likely. It's like meeting a new person: first impressions are *sometimes* incorrect, but a lot of the time they are enough for your intuition to suggest what the person is about. So use your intuition and common sense with this also. I would say if you really are pretty good at your work, you should have more opportunities and not have to jump on the first sketchy offer. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is nonsense. No reputable company would expect anyone to work for free, let alone for an entire month. Run away very fast.

Comment: I have written this not a fresher position. @JoeStrazzere could you give an example of a reputable company giving unpaid internships?

Comment: @vedant1811 I'd like to say - internships common in the **US**, and generally for very low-level positions. If you're qualified for the position, you shouldn't expect to be asked to work in an unpaid internship. People doing this generally do so for the experience, so that they'll be more qualified afterwards and have actual work experience so they'll be accepted into paid positions. I don't know how much of this translates into your country's culture. But given you've said you have 3 years of work experience, I'd say what this person is asking of you is both nonsense and somewhat offensive.